# Get value from Gutenberg SelectControl to php for frontend

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have simple Gutenberg block with google fonts select.

```
el (SelectControl,
{   
    value: fontFamily,
    label: __('Шрифт'),
    options: [                                  
        {
            value: 'Georgia',
            label: 'Georgia'
        },
        { 
            value: 'PT Sans', 
            label: 'PT Sans' 
        },
        { 
            value: 'Amatic SC', 
            label: 'Amatic SC' 
        },
    ],
    onChange: onChangefontFamily,
},),
```

php:

```
function google_fonts_url() {   
  $fonts_url = '';  
  $font_families = array();
  $font_families[] = 'Amatic SC|PT Sans:400,400i';
  $query_args = array(
      'family' => urlencode( implode( '|', $font_families ) ),
      'subset' => urlencode( 'latin,cyrillic' ),
  );
  $fonts_url = add_query_arg( $query_args, 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css' );    
  return $fonts_url; }
```

i need to load only selected font from google.

How to get val from select for this?

Answer (score 0):

Gutenberg saves the attributes of a block in HTML comments inside the post_content. So you need to parse the HTML comments using PHP. One way to do this is using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Lets say your content is saved in post_content as follows:

```
<!-- wp:yourprefix/yourblock {"fontFamily":"Amatic SC"} -->
 <div class="wp-block-yourprefix-yourblock"></div>
<!-- /wp:yourprefix/yourblock -->
```

Then, you can get the contents of the post/page using:

```
$content_post = get_post($my_postid);
$content = $content_post->post_content;
```

This content can then be parsed by the DOMDocument Library to extract the value of select encoded in JSON

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();

//Pass the content to the loadHTML function
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

//Extract Comment Nodes
$comments = $xpath->query('//comment()');

//Extract text from the 1st node
$text = $comments->item(0)->data;

//Match the JSON string and decode to get the selected font value
preg_match('~\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}~', $text,$res);
$fontFamily = json_decode($res[0])->fontFamily;
```

Comment: better way - https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/block-api/block-attributes/#meta

and webfont:

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 fonts = [];
 $('.wp-block-writer').each(function() {
  font = this.style.fontFamily;
  font = font.replace(/\"/g, "");
  if (font != 'Georgia') fonts.push(font);
 });
 if (fonts != '') {
  WebFont.load({
   google: {
    families: fonts
   }
  });
 }
});